# Jersey 1.x - Uplifting Swagger 1.x to 2.x

Tags: jersey, swagger-2.0, swagger-maven-plugin

I have a Jersey application that's currently using Swagger 1.6

Below are the important segments from the pom file of the project

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <apiSources>
                    <apiSource>
                        <springmvc>false</springmvc>
                        <locations>
                            <location>com.example.resource</location>
                        </locations>
                        <schemes>
                            <scheme>http</scheme>
                            <scheme>https</scheme>
                        </schemes>
                        <host>www.example.com:8080</host>
                        <basePath>/api-docs</basePath>
                        <info>
                            <title>Swagger Maven Plugin Sample</title>
                            <version>v1</version>
                            <description>Sample for Swagger Maven Plaugin</description>
                            <termsOfService>
                                http://www.example.com/tos
                            </termsOfService>
                            <contact>
                                <email>abc@test.com</email>
                                <name>Example App</name>
                                <url>http://test.com</url>
                            </contact>
                            <license>
                                <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
                                <name>Apache 2.0</name>
                            </license>
                        </info>
                        <templatePath>${basedir}/templates/strapdown.html.hbs</templatePath>
                        <outputPath>${basedir}/generated/document.html</outputPath>
                        <swaggerDirectory>${basedir}/generated/swagger-ui</swaggerDirectory>
                    </apiSource>
                </apiSources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-hibernate-validations</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.19</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This works fine and the static documentation generated during build process is proper.
When Swagger is updated to use Swagger v3 as below

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

the documentation is generated but the descriptions are missing (seems like the v3 annotations were not considered) although versions of 3.x of the plugin support the Swagger 3 annotations. To solve the problem, the version of the plugin was changed to `3.1.8` but then I end up with the below error during `mvn clean install`.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.8:generate (default) on project example-rest: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.8:generate (default) on project example-rest: null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
    at com.github.kongchen.swagger.docgen.mavenplugin.ApiDocumentMojo.execute (ApiDocumentMojo.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.kongchen.swagger.docgen.AbstractDocumentSource.toSwaggerDocuments (AbstractDocumentSource.java:203)
    at com.github.kongchen.swagger.docgen.mavenplugin.ApiDocumentMojo.execute (ApiDocumentMojo.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

What can be the reason for Null pointer exception, or what can be the reason for the Swagger 3 annotations being not considered although it's supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the plugin with the one below works

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>io.openapitools.swagger</groupId>
   <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.4</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <swaggerConfig>
         <servers>
            <server>
               <url>https://www.example.com:8080/cas/api</url>
            </server>
         </servers>
         <info>
            <title>${project.name}</title>
            <description>${project.description}</description>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </info>
      </swaggerConfig>
      <resourcePackages>com.cerner.careaware.rest.personnel</resourcePackages>
      <useResourcePackagesChildren>true</useResourcePackagesChildren>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/generated/openapi/</outputDirectory>
      <outputFilename>openApiSpec</outputFilename>
      <outputFormats>JSON,YAML</outputFormats>
      <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
      <attachSwaggerArtifact>true</attachSwaggerArtifact>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```